# /etc/sysctl.conf shmall shmmax calculation Oracle DB

Tags: linux, oracle, kernel, sysctl

I have a question about what COULD be the possible impact to a system, if we have the following kernel shmmax and shmall kernel settings:

```
# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
kernel.shmmax = 135456844800
# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 107374182400
kernel.shmmni = 4096
kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128

# free -mt
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        258065     230766      27299      11935       1481      58723
-/+ buffers/cache:     170561      87504
Swap:        16383         52      16331
Total:      274449     230818      43631
```

On that specific server we run only Oracle DB, are the settings correct and if not what could be the impact? Thanks a lot in advance!